# How to add filter method onclick button in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, filter, mongoose-schema

I have a form which has a input field called admissionNumber and the button. In input field when user enter number and click the button then function getAllStudent filter the an array . If admission number match with entered number then other fields (fullname and faculty) automatically filled . How can I do this ? Please someone help me to do this . Thank you

**getAllStudents function** which return students details (admissionNumber,fullname,faculty)

```
 getAllStudents(user._id, token).then((data) => {
  if (data.error) {
    setValues({ ...values, error: data.error });
  } else {
    setValues(data);
  }
});
```

**form fields**

```
<input
            type="text"
            onChange={(event) => {
              setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
            }}
            className="form-control offset-md-2  col-md-6"
            placeholder="Admission Number"
            required
            maxLength="5"
          />

          <button
            // onClick={}
            className="btn rounded ml-4"
            
          >
            Verify
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className="bg-dark rounded">Personal Details</div>
        <div className="row form-group ">
          <input
            type="text"         
            name="studentFullName"
            className="form-control mt-2 offset-md-2 col-md-8"
            placeholder="Student Name"
           
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            name="faculty"
            className="form-control mt-2 offset-md-2 col-md-8"
          />
        </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a function to button `onClick` prop.

Assuming you using a functional component and a state with **students**, **currentUser** and **searchTerm** you can do something like that:

```
const [students] = useState([...])

const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(undefined)

const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState(undefined)


const checkStudent = () => {
    const match = students.find(student  => student.admissionNumber === searchTerm)
    if(match) {
        setCurrentUser(match)
    }
}

return (
    <>
        <button
            onClick={() => checkStudent()}
        />

        <input
            type="text"         
            name="studentFullName"
            className="form-control mt-2 offset-md-2 col-md-8"
            placeholder="Student Name"
            value={currentUser?.fullname}
        />
    </>
)
```